# Как увеличить скорость перехода между фрагментами?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

У меня есть bottom navigation. И у меня часто подзависает приложение, когда я совершаю переходы. Мне кажется я должен реализовать это в потоке просто я не знаю как.

Вот мой код:

```
public void clickAction(View view) {
        ImageButton diaryButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.diary_button);
        ImageButton appointButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.appoint_button);
        ImageButton veriButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.veri_button);

                diaryButton.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Fragment diaryfragment = new DiaryFragment();
                                FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                ft1.add(R.id.content_frame, diaryfragment);
                                ft1.commit();
                            }
                        }
                );

                appointButton.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Fragment appointfragment = new CalendarFragment();
                                FragmentTransaction ft2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                ft2.add(R.id.content_frame, appointfragment);
                                ft2.commit();
                            }
                        }
                );
                veriButton.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Fragment verifragment = new AimsFragment();
                                FragmentTransaction ft3 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                ft3.add(R.id.content_frame, verifragment);
                                ft3.commit();
                            }
                        }
                );




    }
```

Comment: Вопрос еще актуален ?

Comment: Да, этот вопрос пока не решён

Comment: Сделать "легче" сами фрагменты. Что у вас там: много данных? Много вью? Сложные рассчеты?

Comment: Да довольно много

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findViewById`при старте а не где попало.

Фрагменты можно теребонькать примерно так:

```
Fragment appointfragment = new CalendarFragment();
Fragment diaryfragment = new DiaryFragment();
```

применить, как советовали выше интерфейс `implements View.OnClickListener`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.diaryButton:
           loadFragment(diaryfragment)
           break;

       case R.id.button2:
            loadFragment(appointfragment )
           break;


private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    if (fragmentManager != null) {
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Так , как минимум, в 4 раза меньше кода.
Ну и оптимизировать код во фрагментах

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю убрать функцию clickAction() , в XML файле поставить один обработчик нажатий на все 3 фрагмента, объявление ImageButton запихать в класс , а инициализацию в OnCreate() , и почитать Android Data Binding и вообще Android Architecture Components, через него хорошо бы работать, (не плохая рекомендация google, поправьте если что) ,в обработчике в созданном через switch реализовать выбор фрагмента. - это что касается архитектуры. У вас возможно много тяжелых вещей во фрагменте, возможно сам код фрагмента требует доработок.

PS. Добавляйте информации для развития темы !!!

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете повесить один обработчик кликов на все кнопки сразу. Это делается в классе:

```
public class Foo extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

потом в методе onCreate прописать:

```
mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
mButton.setOnClickListener(this);  

mButton2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

ниже метода onCreate вам откроется возможность писать в методе onClick все, что нужно для Ваших кнопок:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.button:
               // действия
               break;

           case R.id.button2:
               // действия
               break;
```

Я в интернете читал разные мнения по этому поводу. Кто-то говорит, что это лишь сокращает количество строчек в коде и никак не влияет на память. А кто-то пишет, что она экономится существенно, так как на создание каждого объекта резервируется свое место в ней. 
Я лично считаю, что и на каждый отображенный символ в коде также затрачивается хоть немножко памяти)))